# Get Song Currently Playing In Windows Media Player

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

Using C# how can I get the name of the song, artists etc that is currently playing in Windows Media Player? Applications like MSN Messenger / Google Talk do this. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For C#

I spent hours trying to get it to work for my program.
Finally I figured it out.

This solution is assuming you have either the windows media player control ON a form in your project or have created the object through code..

1. create a new Windows Media Player Song object and point it to a file
2. create a string to hold your artist, then pull the artist info from the song object
3. create a string to hold your title, then pull the artist info from the song object.

   ```
           WMPLib.IWMPMedia song = wmp.newMedia(@"C:\SongName.mp3");         
           string tmpArtist = song.getItemInfo("Artist");
           string tmpTitle = song.getItemInfo("Title");
   ```

it was so simple i slapped myself when i finished, and seeing as i couldnt find the answer anywhere, i have provided it for the next guy.

Comment: This doesn't seem to get the **currently playing** song in WMP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Wmp.dll.

This link will also be helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563844(VS.85).aspx