# get currently playing song name from media player through java programming

Tags: java, windows-media-player

Is there any way through which i can get the name of the song being played in my window media player using java programming.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use native code. The hard (but free) way is to write [Java Native Interface](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/) code yourself. The easier way is to use a product which does the hard work for you, for example [EZ-JCOM](http://www.ezjcom.com/). I've used it before and it has been ok.

To then find out how to get the currently playing song, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140560/get-song-currently-playing-in-windows-media-player).